# Use "at variable" ($@) on the right hand side of a rule in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have several targets with different prerequisites but the same building rule which I want to reuse for all of my targets.

Here is the makefile I wrote for this task:

```
test1 := a b
test2 := b c

all: test1 test2

test1 test2: $($@)
  @echo $@
  @echo $($@)
  @echo $^
```

If I run `make` I'll get the following output:

```
test1
a b

test2
b c
```

What I expect is:

```
test1
a b
a b
test2
b c
b c
```

As you can see, the problem is $^ is empty. It seems like I can't use `$($@)` on the right-hand side of a rule because it just expands to nothing so `$^` is empty and that's why `make` doesn't even warn me that there are no targets for `a` `b` and `c`. Notice that inside the body $($@) works just as expected.

I want `$($@)` to be equivalet to `$(test1)` when I call `make test1` and to `$(test2)` when I call `make test2` so my makefile would be equivalent to the following makefile:

```
test1 := a b
test2 := b c

all: test1 test2

test1: $(test1)
  <build-command>

test2: $(test2)
  <the same build-command>
```

But I don't want to repeat these 2 lines for every `testn` I have, I want single build rule for different targets with different dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is highly unclear, but I'll take a stab at it. I think this is what you want:

```
all: test1 test2

test1: a b
test2: b c

test1 test2:
    @echo building $@ from $^

a b c d:
    @echo how to build $@?...
```

**EDIT:**

All right, now this is starting to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If what you want is one rule that will cover all of your `testn` targets, what I wrote above will do it.

If what you want is to expand the variable whose name is the name of the target, in that target's prerequisite list (which strikes me as an obscure solution in search of a problem), this will do it:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
test1: $$($$@)
    @echo building $@ from $^
```

Comment: sorry if it's unclear, I've updated question, I hope it's better now

Comment: thanks, this magical secondexpansion was exactly what I was looking for